# Angular 6 import SCSS from node_modules with assets

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli, css-loader

I currently have a library which exports some SCSS with paths to fonts laying in a subfolder.

- nodemodules/library/fonts/font.scss
- font files e.g. in nodemodules/library/fonts/bold/xyz.eot

With the SCSS looking like the following in my font.scss in the node_modules folder

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Daimler";
   font-weight: "normal";
   font-style: "italic";
   src: url($font-path + '.eot') format("embedded-opentype"),
   url($font-path + '.ttf') format("ttf");
}
```

The file will be imported in the angular project in the main.scss file in the src-folder. The folder will be copied from the angular build to assets with the following setting

```
{
   "glob": "**/*",
   "input": "nodemodules/library/fonts/",
   "output": "/assets/fonts"
}
```

My question is how the $font-path should look like, or what i need to fix the problem. What i already tried and didn't work (always cant resolve the path):

```
./assets/fonts/bold/xyz.eot (can't resolve because relativ path is wrong from main.scss, but should be correct since that will be the destination the files will be copied to from the angular build)

/src/assets/fonts/bold/xyz.eot (building the project works, but path is wrong on runtime)
```

The problem is that CSS-Loader will always check the urls, when building the app it always tries to resolve the path to src/assets which obviously has no files in it, because they will only get copied to the destination folder (from the cli-config).

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /src/assets/fonts/bold/xyz.eot (building the project works, but path
>   is wrong on runtime)

When your app builds default all files will be in your dist folder.
It will look something like this

- assets
- index.html
- *bunch of js files and other*

You won't have an src folder on root.

Absolute path would be `/assets/fonts/bold/xyz.eot`

I think relative path would be `./nodemodules/library/fonts/bold/xyz.eot`

Comment: Yeah that would be the correct path while developing but on runtime there is no more node_modules folder so the files couldn't be found.

Comment: If I am not mistaken angular cli will convert paths when you build your application for production.

Comment: Should have trie `/assets/fonts/bold/xyz.eot` --> Works. Maybe TS import paths but i dont think SCSS paths, they always have to be relative to the dist folder. Just did a rookie mistake, thanks for your hint :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to give you a definitive answer, since folder structure varies from project to project, but it looks like you need to use `--deploy-url` flag from Angular CLI.

Here's an excerpt from my project's package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "prod": "ng build --deploy-url /assets/analytics/dist/",
  "dev": "ng build --deploy-url /assets/analytics/dist/ --watch",
  "test": "ng test"
}
```

In my case, all the fonts are mixed with main Angular CLI generated bundles in dist folder. The `styles.css` file is in there as well and I have no problems with broken paths.

Again, like I said, your folder structure may differ, but `deploy-url` flag is a way to go.